# Copy variables from one TensorFlow graph to another

Tags: tensorflow

I have two tensorflow graphs. One for training and the other for evaluation. They share a lot of variable names. When I evaluate a model I want to copy all variable values from the train graph to the test graph. Obviously, I can do it via tf.train.Saver, but this solution seems not very appropriate to me, especially the fact that we have to use the disk for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you speak about multiple graphs, I assume you mean something like:

```
g1 = tf.Graph()
with g1.as_default():
  # add your stuff

g2 = tf.Graph()
with g2.as_default():
  # add other stuff
```

If this is correct, then are you sure you really need two graphs? Can't you have one graph consisting of two connected components?

Using multiple graphs is [discouraged](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs20si/lectures/slides_01.pdf) (p 47) because:

> - Multiple graphs require multiple sessions, each will try to use all available resources by default
> - Can't pass data between them without passing them through python/numpy, which doesn't work in distributed
> - It’s better to have disconnected subgraphs within one graph

This also gives you a solution how to pass variables in a non-distributed setting.

Comment: The problem is the following. I have a model. I have two instances of it, one taking input from queue, the other from another queue. One queue is for the train set, the other is for the test set. Is there any way to swap inputs without using feed_dict?

Comment: As far as I understand, using feed_dict explicitly is also discourage, and queues should be used instead.

Comment: @KonstantinSolomatov If you will provide some less abstract example, I will try to take a look a little bit later. Regarding queues vs feeds: you are correct. This is for performance reasons. Feeds are mostly to play around and experiment.

Comment: Ok. Will create a separate question for it.

Comment: Here's a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43646547/how-to-structure-the-model-for-training-and-evaluation-on-the-test-set Thanks!

Comment: @KonstantinSolomatov will take a look slightly later

Comment: @SalvadorDali building multiple graphs is actually encouraged by people at Google: https://github.com/tensorflow/nmt#building-training-eval-and-inference-graphs