# How to structure the model for training and evaluation on the test set

Tags: tensorflow

I want to train a model. Every 1000 steps, I want to evaluate it on the test set and write it to the tensorboard log. However, there's a problem. I have a code like this:

```
image_b_train, label_b_train = tf.train.shuffle_batch(...)
out_train = model.inference(image_b_train)
accuracy_train = tf.reduce_mean(...)

image_b_test, label_b_test = tf.train.shuffle_batch(...)
out_test = model.inference(image_b_test)
accuracy_test = tf.reduce_mean(...)
```

where model inference declares the variables in the model. However, there's a problem. For the test set I have a separate queue, and I can't swap one queue for another with tensorflow.

Currently I solved the problem by creating 2 graphs, one for training and the other for testing. I copy from one graph to the other with tf.train.Saver. Another solution might be to use tf.get_variable, but this is a global variable, and I don't like it because my code becomes less reusable.

Comment: Another way to solve this, might be instead of creating functions for inference and loss, create a class. In a constructor I will create all the variables, and in the inference method, I will instantiate graph based on the variables. 

It would be nice if somebody with experience share how they structure their models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need two graphs. These graphs can share variables. This can be done by:

1. Using Keras layers (from `tf.contrib.keras`) which let you define the model once and use it to compute two inference graphs
2. Using slim-style layers (from `tf.layers`) with `tf.get_variable` and reuse
3. Using `tf.make_template` to make your own model-like object which can be called once to build the training graph and once to build the inference graph
4. Using `tf.estimator.Estimator` which lets you define a model function once and runs it automatically for training and evaluation for you

There are other options, but any of these is well-supported and should unblock you.

Comment: Btw, how have you learned all this? Which materials have you used?

Comment: Mostly reading the source code and discussing thing with other users (I work on TensorFlow at Google)

Comment: It seems that `tf.get_variable` can only share variables in one graph, but not among multiple graphs? How do you realize that variables can be shared between multiple graphs?